# Why does this code output a 64 if the input is a character?

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//A simple program that asks for an integer and prints it back out.

int main()
{
    int a; 
    printf("Type an integer: ");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("The integer you typed is: %d",a);
}
```

If the user types in a character such as `X` then the output will always be a 64 for some reason. Why does this happen?

Comment: @CherubimAnand: It's not an ASCII thing. X isn't even ASCII 64.

Comment: @user2357112 Ya... its undefined behavior.. i got it wrong

Comment: In addition to what Sourav said, it's always a good idea to validate inputs (or arguments when in a function). If what is received is not what you intended, give a warning or error message. This is especially beneficial for helping debug a more robust problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

In case a matching failure happens for `scanf()` ("X" is not a match for `%d`), the supplied argument remains unassigned, and as the argument is an uninitialized local variable, the value remains indeterminate.

Related, from `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.2

> [...] If
>   the input item is not a matching sequence, the execution of the directive fails: this
>   condition is a matching failure. [...]

Attempting to use that value invokes UB. From `C11` annex J.2, *undefined behavior*

> The value of an object with automatic storage duration is used while it is
>   indeterminate.

Thus, you should always

1. Initialize your local variables
2. Check the return value of `scanf()`.